# Does our Snowflake integration using Snowflake's Snowpipe service or is the connector only using the standard S3/copy bulk upload mechanism?

Tags: continuous-integration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

This is a question directly from one of our clients who is currently setting up the Snowflake outbound integration. If it is S3, were there ever discussions of using Snowpipe in future as an expanded integration?

Nothing tried as of this point beyond reviewing docs which look to allude to S3

Comment: Hi - what integration are you referring to? I think you’ll need to provide a lot more information about what you are trying to achieve and how you’ve implemented it in order to get a useful answer

Comment: Snowpipe is an automated *ingestion* service. The most common use would leverage an object storage integration (like S3) + a notification integration. When a new file arrives in object storage, a notification is sent to Snowflake to ingest the file into a table. Snowpipe can be used on an internal stage, however, you will need to find a method to trigger the notification channel with the API.  Snowpipe is used behind the scenes with the Kafka connector as well.